# Change license code of the Windows 7 RTM with Oct 22nd ship of real copy

Tags: windows-7, windows, license, license-key, msdn

So, I've downloaded the RTM of Windows 7 from my MSDN license. I, like a good little boy, will not run that OS as my main machine license (since it's only for *testing* purposes).

So if I install the RTM on my machine using the MSDN key, can I just change the license key and reactivate when my physical copy shows up on October 22nd?

Any gotchas to watch for?

Comment: duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/19168/can-i-change-my-windows-7-product-key-at-a-later-date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you'll be able to change the product key of the Windows 7 install once you get the new key. Just go to "Control Panel - System and Security - System", then scroll all the way down and select "Change product key" and enter in your new key.

The catch is you'll need to have the same edition of Windows 7 installed that your product key is for. If you'll be getting Windows 7 Home Premium, then you'll need to have Windows 7 Home Premium installed for your product key to work. If you have Ultimate installed and the product key is for Home Premium, then you'll need to repave and install Ultimate for your new product key to work.

The install disc ISO images on MSDN are the same as the shipping product.

Comment: My intent is to install x64 Professional (from the Ultimate ISO via the "delete the EI.CFG file" technique and then use the code when my upgrade arrives. I just want to avoid the double-repave.

Thanks!